# Weird JSON parsing error?

Tags: json, parsing, nsstring, nsarray, nsurlconnection

I used to be able to parse this JSON just perfectly with no errors at all but all of a sudden it stopped working and it is not my API keys...

This is what I'm trying to parse: http://pastebin.com/vv8ScBfZ

This is my parsing code:

```
NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *flighttrackjson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonresponse options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&myError];
NSArray *FlightStatus =  [flighttrackjson objectForKey:@"flightStatuses"];
NSString *FlightID = [FlightStatus valueForKey:@"flightId"];
NSString *DepartACode = [FlightStatus valueForKey:@"departureAirportFsCode"];
NSString *ArivalACode = [FlightStatus valueForKey:@"arrivalAirportFsCode"];
NSArray *DepartATime = [FlightStatus valueForKey:@"departureDate"];
NSArray *AriveATime = [FlightStatus valueForKey:@"arrivalDate"];
NSString *DepartTimeString = [DepartATime valueForKey:@"dateLocal"];
NSString *ArriveTimeString = [AriveATime valueForKey:@"dateUtc"];
NSArray *Delays = [FlightStatus valueForKey:@"delays"];
NSString *DepartDelayMinutes = [Delays valueForKey:@"departureGateDelayMinutes"];
NSString *ArriveDelayMinutes = [Delays valueForKey:@"arrivalGateDelayMinutes"];
NSArray *AirportInfo = [FlightStatus valueForKey:@"airportResources"];
NSString *DepartTerminal = [AirportInfo valueForKey:@"departureTerminal"];
NSString *DepartAGate = [AirportInfo valueForKey:@"departureGate"];
NSString *ArriveTerminal = [AirportInfo valueForKey:@"arrivalTerminal"];
NSString *ArriveAGate = [AirportInfo valueForKey:@"arrivalGate"];
NSString *BaggageClaim = [AirportInfo valueForKey:@"baggage"];
flightID.text=FlightID;
DepartCode.text=DepartACode;
ArrivalCode.text=ArivalACode;
DepartTime.text=DepartTimeString;
ArriveTime.text=ArriveTimeString;
DepartDelay.text=DepartDelayMinutes;
ArriveDelay.text=ArriveDelayMinutes;
DepartTerm.text=DepartTerminal;
DepartGate.text=DepartAGate;
ArriveTerm.text=ArriveTerminal;
ArriveGate.text=ArriveAGate;
Baggage.text=BaggageClaim;
```

When I run that, I get this error:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8aa85f0'
```

No, I am not trying to assign the value of array to a string. So I am quite confused here.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Read the error message.  Look at where it's being raised.

Comment: @HotLicks Don't expect the impossible. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No, I am not trying to assign the value of array to a string

Oh yes you do.

```
FlightStatus = [flighttrackjson objectForKey:@"flightStatuses"];
FlightID = [FlightStatus valueForKey:@"flightId"];
```

`FlightStatus` is an array, not a dictionary (use for example JSONlint to pretty-print the JSON, you'll see it).

Furthermore: I suspect there are several similar errors like this in your code, one particular being that `flightId` corresponds to an `NSNumber` and not an `NSString` - you'll also get a crash from that.

Please study the official reference of JSON and the documentation of the `NSJSONSerialization` class to see which JSON data types map to which Foundation classes (it's quite logical, by the way).

Comment: Sorry about that, thanks for the tips, I'll be sure to read more to educate myself.